# Unable to connect to server local PgAdmin4 to RDS Server VPC

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, pgadmin-4, aws-security-group

I am unable to connect to the RDS from local postgres pgAdmin4. I have my RDS publicly accessible. I have also configured inbound security group rule from my Ip and any Ips. I have also turned off Windows Defender firewall.
Hostname is all correct and 5432 is the port I am trying to connect to. Any suggestions why I am unable to connect? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to recheck in following order

1. Check if the connection credentials are correct i.e. host, port, db, username, password
2. Check if the rds is publicly available
3. Go to the security tab from rds console and check if the attached security group has inbound rules which allow connection from your IP
4. Re diagnose the issue by connecting with the same credentials from the postgres command line i.e. psql -h {host} -d {db} .....